# How do I show that this map is not a measure on IN?

Tags: measure-theory

Hello I have a question why the following map is not a measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

> let us define $$\mu:P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow [0,\infty];\,\,\,\,\mu(A)=0\,\,\,\text{A is finite, else} \,\,\,\mu(A)=\infty$$

My idea was the following, I wanted to show that $\mu$ is not sigma sub additive since each measure is sigma sub additive. Thus take $A_i=\{1,2,3,…,i\}$ then clearly $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\mathbb{N}$$therefore $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)=\infty$ since the natural numbers are not finite. On the other hand $$\mu(A_i)=0$$ since $A_i$ is finite. Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(A_i)=0$ And this shows that it is not sigma sub additive and thus not a measure.

Does this work ore did I made some thinking error?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: Perfect thanks!